# YYYMMDD Conversion to MM/DD/YYYY in Power QUery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a column named `DimDateKey` in PowerQuery and it is formatted as YYYYMMDD i.e. 20150201 and I want to convert it to MM/DD/YY and I have had no luck finding the syntax for this.

I have tried this which works in a regular excel sheet:

```
DATE(RIGHT([DimDateKey],4),MID([DimDateKey],4,2),LEFT([DimDateKey],2))
```

But I get

> Expression error: The Name DATE was not recognized. Is it Spelled
>   Correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out

Step 1: Add a custom column
Step 2: Format it as  `=Date.FromText([DimDateKey])`

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the Data Type to Date.  The Data Type button is on the Home ribbon, in the Transform section, or you can right-click the column and choose Change Type.

Note the column needs to be Data Type: Text for this to work.  Presumably due to an overly-rigid PQ evaluation engine, converting Data Type Number (containing the same YYYYMMDD value) returns an Error.